# Moved PostgreSQL 8.4 tables to a tablespace on an SSD, but still getting 4MB/s writes to old HDD

Tags: ssd, postgresql

I first made a postgres-owned directory on the SSD and created the tablespace like so:

```
CREATE TABLESPACE ssd_tablespace LOCATION '/ssd/pgdata';
```

I proceeded to move important tables and all indices on them (this is showing just a single partition, and I altered the parent table too):

```
ALTER TABLE coreg_2010_a SET TABLESPACE ssd_tablespace;
ALTER INDEX coreg_2010_a_pkey SET TABLESPACE ssd_tablespace;
ALTER TABLE visits_2010_a SET TABLESPACE ssd_tablespace;
ALTER INDEX visits_2010_a_pkey SET TABLESPACE ssd_tablespace;
```

All operations were successful, and I confirmed the tablespace has been set in psql. There are foreign keys as well between the tables moved, but those are not indexes that can be moved.

`iostat` shows me that I'm there's a little write activity on the SSD (though not much) through an ongoing script which is doing `INSERT` operations into the tables I've moved. However, the vast majority of the write activity is on the old hard disk for some reason (and I'm only writing to tables in ssd_tablespace). Furthermore, the total size of the tables with indices seems to exceed the space used up on the SSD, though I have not confirmed this properly yet.

Why am I still getting writes to my old hard drive if the tables being inserted into (and their indices) have been moved to a new tablespace on a new hard drive?

For reference, here is what `iostat -dxk 5` shows with an 5-second interval. `/dev/xvde1` is the old hard drive, while `/dev/xvdc1` is the SSD associated with ssd_tablespace:

```
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s   r/s   w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
xvde1             0.00   486.60  0.00 453.40     0.00  3760.00    16.59     0.85    1.87   1.87  84.72
xvdb1             0.00     1.20  0.00  0.80     0.00     8.00    20.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
xvdc1             0.00    26.20  0.00 11.20     0.00   149.60    26.71     0.00    0.29   0.14   0.16

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s   r/s   w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
xvde1             0.00   561.40  0.00 523.60     0.00  4340.00    16.58     0.86    1.65   1.65  86.40
xvdb1             0.00     1.20  0.00  0.60     0.00     7.20    24.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
xvdc1             0.00    26.20  0.00 13.20     0.00   157.60    23.88     0.02    1.21   0.06   0.08

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s   r/s   w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
xvde1             0.00   524.80  0.00 489.40     0.00  4056.00    16.58     0.85    1.72   1.73  84.56
xvdb1             0.00     1.00  0.00  2.00     0.00    12.00    12.00     0.00    1.20   0.40   0.08
xvdc1             0.00    24.60  0.00 10.80     0.00   141.60    26.22     0.00    0.07   0.07   0.08
```

As requested, here is output of `iostat -dx 5`:

```
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s   r/s   w/s   rsec/s   wsec/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
xvde1             3.00  1078.20 31.40 469.00  2664.00 12379.20    30.06     1.29    2.57   1.46  73.04
xvdb1             0.00     1.00  0.00  0.60     0.00    12.80    21.33     0.00    1.33   1.33   0.08
xvdc1             0.00     7.40  0.00  5.00     0.00    99.20    19.84     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s   r/s   w/s   rsec/s   wsec/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
xvde1             6.00  1067.60 32.80 425.40  2768.00 11944.00    32.11     1.37    3.00   1.53  70.16
xvdb1             0.00     1.00  0.00  0.60     0.00    12.80    21.33     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
xvdc1             0.00     6.80  0.00  6.00     0.00   102.40    17.07     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
```

Comment: add please output: iostat -dx 5

Comment: added as requested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're only talking writes, that's probably because your transaction log in the pg_xlog directory is still on the old drive. I'd suggest moving the tables back to the regular harddrive and move the pg_xlog directory (which is the one that takes sync writes) to the SSD.

Comment: Thanks, this must be it. Reads are fast and directly off the SSD, I was just scared I was storing a bunch of table data on the HDD without realizing. Since the pg_xlog gets such heavy write activity, I'm guessing it wouldn't be a good idea to put it on the SSD, lest it quickly erodes. Is there any other way to reduce xlog activity? I'm not processing bank transactions or something, so losing a few writes is not a real problem.

Comment: If you're willing to lose some transactions while maintaining the crash-safetyness, you can turn off synchronous_commit. It will help in at least some cases.